# Racket, writing function that find nth element in list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

In order to understand functional programing, please help me to write a function that output nth element of a list,

Allowed command:

```
define  lambda  cond  else  empty  empty?  first  rest  cons  list

list?  =  equal?  and  or  not  +  -  *  /  <  <=  >  >=
```

Sample output:

> (fourth-element '(a b c d e))                      => d
>
> (fourth-element '(x (y z) w h j))                  => h
>
> (fourth-element '((a b) (c d) (e f) (g h) (i j)))  => (list 'g 'h)
>   or  ‘(g h)
>
> (fourth-element '(a b c))                          => empty

I could write this in python, but I am not family with racket syntax,

```
def element(lst, x=0):
  counter = x;
  if (counter >= 3):
    return lst[0]
  else:
    return element(lst[1:],x+1)

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(element(a))
```

> The Output is 4
>   Comparing with code above in python. What is equivalent behavior in function that create local variable counter. What is "keyword" for return

Comment: Nobody is going to do your homework for you. We can help, but then we need a specific problem and you need to show effort. And of course, if you don't show code the answers won't show code.

Comment: @Sylwester Can you refer me some code example in racket because reading document does not help me much. I need sample code to start. Here I try to start to write a recursive function, but I create local variable and racket gives me error that a local variable is not top-level- variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you came up with an answer of your own. Nice work! I would recommend a more generic `nth` procedure that takes a `counter` as an argument. This allows you to get any element in the input list

```
(define (nth lst counter)
  (cond ((null? lst) (error 'nth "index out of bounds"))
        ((= counter 0) (first lst))
        (else (nth (rest lst) (- counter 1)))))
```

Now if you want a procedure that only returns the 4th element, we create a new procedure which specializes the generic `nth`

```
(define (fourth-element lst)
  (nth lst 3))
```

That's it. Now we test them out with your inputs

```
(define a `(1 2 3 (4 5) 7))
(define b `(1 2 3))
(define c `((a b)(c d)(e f)(g h)(i j)))
(define d `(a b c))

(fourth-element a) ; '(4 5)
(fourth-element b) ; nth: index out of bounds
(fourth-element c) ; '(g h)
(fourth-element d) ; nth: index out of bounds
```

Note, when the counter goes out of bounds, I chose to raise an `error` instead of returning a value (`"empty"`) like your program does. Returning a value makes it impossible to know whether you actually found a value in the list, or if the default was returned. In the example below, notice how your procedure cannot differentiate the two inputs

```
(define d `(a b c))
(define e `(a b c ,"empty"))

; your implementation
(fourth-element e) ; "empty" 
(fourth-element d) ; "empty"

; my implementation
(fourth-element e) ; "empty" 
(fourth-element d) ; error: nth: index out of bounds
```

If you don't want to throw an error, there's *another* way we can encode `nth`. Instead of returning nth *element*, we can return the nth *pair* whose head contains the element in question.

Below, `nth` *always* returns a list. If the list is empty, no element was found. Otherwise, the nth element is the `first` element in the result.

```
(define (nth lst counter)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((= counter 0) lst)
        (else (nth (rest lst) (- counter 1)))))

(define (fourth-element lst)
  (nth lst 3))

(define a `(1 2 3 (4 5) 7))
(define b `(1 2 3))
(define c `((a b)(c d)(e f)(g h)(i j)))
(define d `(a b c))
(define e `(a b c ,"empty"))

(fourth-element a) ; '((4 5) 7)
(fourth-element b) ; '()
(fourth-element c) ; '((g h) (i j))
(fourth-element d) ; '()
(fourth-element e) ; '("empty")
```

Hopefully this gets you to start thinking about *domain* (procedure input type) and *codomain* (procedure output type).

In general, you want to design procedures that have natural descriptions like:

- *" `nth` takes a list and a number and always returns a list"* (best)
- *" `nth` takes a list and a number and returns an element of the list or raises an exception if the element is not found"* (good, but now you *must* handle errors)

Avoid procedures like

- *" `nth` takes a list and a number and returns an element of the list or a string literal `"empty"` if the element is not found"* (unclear codomain)

By thinking about your procedure's domain and codomain, you have awareness of how your function will work as it's inserted in various parts of your program. Using many procedures with poorly-defined domains lead to disastrous spaghetti code. Conversely, well-defined procedures can be assembled like building blocks with little (or no) glue code necessary.

Comment: Very Specific. Thank you very Sir/Madam.

Comment: While `cdr` always return a list `assoc` is an example were it doesn't. It returns `(or/c pair? #f)`. Consistent return is not a typical Scheme feature, but up to the designer which isn\t OP but a professor so while I like the idea of failure (I even assume right input and let `cdr` fail) one cannot do that when implementing a predefined contract. I would agree OP could do this if the examples didn't define the `empty` outcome.

Comment: *"... `cdr` always return a list"* - but `(cdr (cons 1 2))` returns `2`. I agree with everything else you're saying :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to write it in Python:

```py
def nth(lst, idx=0):
  if (len(lst) == 0):
    return "empty"
  elif (idx == 0):
    return lst[0]
  else:
    return nth(lst[1:], idx - 1)

nth([1,2,3], 1)
# ==> 2

def fourth-element(lst):
  return nth(lst, 4)
```

Same in Scheme/Racket:

```scm
(define (nth lst idx)
  (cond ((empty? lst) empty)  ; more effiecent than (= (length lst) 0)
        ((= idx 0) (first lst))
        (else (nth (rest lst) (- idx 1))))

(nth '(1 2 3) 1)
; ==> 2

(define (fourth-element lst)
  (nth lst 4))
```

There is no keyword for `return`. Every form returns the last evaluated code:

```scm
(if (< 4 x)
    (bar x)
    (begin 
      (display "print this")
      (foo x)))
```

This `if` returns either the result of `(bar x)` or it prints "print this" then returns the result of `(foo x)`. The reason is that for the two outcomes of the `if` they are the tail expressions.

```scm
(define (test x)
  (+ x 5)
  (- x 3))
```

This function has two expressions. The first is dead code since it has no side effect and since it's not a tail expression, but the `(- x 3)` is what this function returns.

```scm
(define (test x y)
  (define xs (square x))
  (define ys (square y))
  (sqrt (+ xs ys)))
```

This has 3 expressions. The first two has side effects that it binds two local variables while the third uses this to compute the returned value.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful for rookie in Racket.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define a `(1 2 3 (4 5) 7))
(define b `(1 2 3))
(define c `((a b)(c d)(e f)(g h)(i j)))
(define d `(a b c))

(define (my-lst-ref lst counter)
  (cond[(>= counter 3) (first lst)]
       [else (my-lst-ref (rest lst)(+ counter 1))]
       )
  )

(define (fourth-element lst)
  (cond[(>= (list-length lst) 4) (my-lst-ref lst 0)]
       [else "empty"]))

(fourth-element a)
(fourth-element c)
(fourth-element d)
```

Output:

> (list 4 5) 
>   (list 'g 'h) 
>   "empty"